# How to change the order of my results?

Tags: r

I have some data got from the database and then I execute the floowing code

```
for(i in length(lreturns):1)
stand[i] <- sd(lreturns[i : (i + 8)])
rolling <- stand * sqrt(252) * 100
```

and get this

```
[1] 203058612348 
[9]  158456851532156 
[17]  563548153215322 
[25] 271515527841123222 
[33]NA NANANANANANANA 
[41] NANANANANANA
```

My question is how to show the NA first, and afterward everything else ? I am using R.

```
[1]NA NANANANANANANA 
[9] NANANANANANA2030 
[17]586123481584 
[25] 568515321565635 
[33] 48153215322271515 
[41] 527841123222
```

Comment: reproducible example please?  `?sort` ?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I would just write

```
c(rolling[is.na(rolling)], rolling[!is.na(rolling)])
```

If you don't care about the non-NA values being sorted, you can use `sort()` as @BenBolker suggested in the comments. There is an argument `na.last` in this function

```
sort(rolling, na.last = FALSE)
```